# How do I remove line breaks that these WordPress functions produce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, line-breaks

I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
<div class="entry">
<?php
echo the_date() . " " . the_category();
if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'content' || is_single() ) { the_content(__('Continue Reading &rarr;', 'woothemes') ); } else { the_excerpt(); }
if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'content' || is_singular() ) wp_link_pages( $page_link_args );
    ?>
```

Right now the output looks something like this:

```
July 7, 2011
Sports
```

I want to remove the line break between the two so that it looks more like this (all on one line):

```
July 7, 2011 Sports
```

Answer (score 0):

Those functions should not have line breaks built into them.  Chances are what you are seeing is due to opening and closing your PHP, or a stray `<br/>` somewhere else.  Show us the entire code so we can help.  Otherwise, try this:

```
echo the_date() . " " . the_category();
```

Comment: @Brian, edit your original post please.  Also, can you include a link to your page?  Perhaps the line is being broken by the design, and not server-side.

Comment: thanks for the help. That is a snippet of my code...I'm also looking to hardcode the date and category into each post right before the paragraph text begins.

Answer (score 0):

Hey dont use `echo` with `the_date()` and `the_category()` functions, as they itself return echoed data.